# How to find a match in list and 2d list

Tags: python, dataframe, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a list and 2d list that I would like to return only the matching values. For instance I have number 10 that I would like to find a match in df2.

```
Df1 = [10]

Df2 = [[2,4],[5,10,13,],[2,3], 
[2,6,10,20]]
```

Expected Output

```
Df3 = [[5,10,10,13], 
[2,6,10,10,20]]
```

Comment: what are we supposed to do, if we have more than one element in DF1?

Comment: You forgot to post the code you're having difficulty with

Comment: Can you clarify if `Df1` can contain more than one element? If yes what should happen? And why do you have twice the searched item in the output? Do you want to insert it? Are the list always sorted? Can you have more than once the same item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be better ways but here you go:

```
Df3 = []
for x in Df1:
     for sub_list in Df2:
             if x in sub_list:
                     Df3.append(sub_list)
```

Note that the output is `[[5, 10, 13], [2, 6, 10, 20]]`, not `[[5,10,10,13],  [2,6,10,10,20]]`

Comment: Looks like he also inserts the element that he is checking for, so maybe `sub_list.append(x)` and `sub_list.sort()` could be added.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `set` operations to check if any item is common:

```
S = set(Df1)

out = [l for l in Df2 if S.intersection(l)]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 10, 13], [2, 6, 10, 20]]
```

If you have several items and want to match all:

```
Df1 = [10, 13]

S = set(Df1)

out = [l for l in Df2 if S.issubset(l)]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 10, 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way using nested *for* loops (to allow for Df1 containing more than one element):

```
Df1 = [10]

Df2 = [
    [2,4],
    [5,10,13],
    [2,3], 
    [2,6,10,20]
    ]

Df3 = []

for m in Df1:
    for e in Df2:
        try:
            i = e.index(m)
            (_e := e[::]).insert(i, m)
            Df3.append(_e)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(Df3)
```

**Output:**

```
[[5, 10, 10, 13], [2, 6, 10, 10, 20]]
```